# How to improve my solution in codility test?

Tags: java

```
class Solution {


public int solution(int[] A) {
    long totalSum = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i< A.length; i++)
    {
        totalSum += A[i];  // same as sumright ok till now
    }
    long mindiff = 0;
    long tempdiff = 0;
    long part1 = 0, part2;
    part1 += A[0];
    part2 = totalSum ;
    mindiff = Math.abs(part1 - part2);
    /*System.out.println("part1 is"+part1);
    System.out.println("part2 is"+part2);       
    System.out.println(mindiff);
    */for(int i = 1; i< A.length; i++)
    {
        //System.out.println("loopindex is "+i);
        part1 += A[i];
        part2 -= A[i];
        tempdiff = Math.abs(part1 - part2);
        /*System.out.println("part1 is"+part1);
        System.out.println("part2 is"+part2);       
        System.out.println("tempdiff is"+ tempdiff);
        */
        if(tempdiff < mindiff)
        {
            mindiff = tempdiff;
        }
        //System.out.println(mindiff);
    }

    return (int)mindiff;

}
}
```

Please check this link

https://codility.com/demo/results/demoD28TY3-RD4/

Is there any way, we can get the test inputs which are used for validating a codility test?

I got wrong answer for two cases

-- small elements
-- two elements

Please advise.

Comment: why the downvotes, this is a reasonably good question

Comment: @AdriaanKoster No it's not. It has no real value being the Codility demo test, not to mention that the best thing the OP can do is to figure it out by himself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not useful to have SO users doing other people's Codility demo exercises.

Comment: The solution code above was written by OP and the codility test result clearly shows what the problem is. This satisfies the main criteria for a SO question, even though I agree OP could probably explain better why he/she doesn't understand the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your are splitting after the last element, resulting in an empty halve.

Change your second iteration to:

```
for(int i = 1; i< A.length - 1; i++)
```

And don't forget to consider what should happen if A is empty or has length 1.

EDIT A fixed version should appear here shortly: https://codility.com/demo/results/demoZFZ6ED-2CP/